# How to establish a server with a unix domain socket

Tags: sockets, unix, server, ocaml, unix-socket

I am trying to establish a server with OCaml using a unix domain socket. I tried the following:

```ml
let sock_addr = Unix.ADDR_UNIX sock_file_path in
Unix.establish_server server_loop sock_addr;
```

With `sock_file_path` being a path to a `.sock` file.

But I always get one of the following errors:

- if the file in `sock_file_path` doesn't exist, the exception `Unix.EPERM` is raised (Operation not permitted).
- if the file in `sock_file_path` exists and is just an empty file, the exception `Unix.EADDRINUSE` is raised (Address already in use).

In both cases, it is the call to `bind` that raises the exception in `Unix.establish_server`.

Is there a particular way in which the file needs to be initialized for it to work?

Comment: The filename being used for the socket should not exist before binding it; getting an error in that case is expected.

Comment: I can't reproduce an EPERM when the socket file doesn't exist. Do you have permission to create files in the directory you're trying to put it in?

Comment: That's weird, I set the rights with `sudo chmod -R a+rwX` on that directory just to be sure and the error persists. I also tried creating other file with the same binary in that repository with no problem. Using an unnamed socket `sock_file_path = ""` seems to work on the other hand.

Comment: Except that with an unnamed socket file, connections don't work with an `Invalid argument` error.

Comment: If you're on Linux, an empty path string might end up using an abstract namespace socket.

Comment: I am on Linux, is using an abstract namespace an issue? Is there a way to recover it?

Comment: (also on Linux the process needs write and execute permissions on a directory to create a socket file in it. Other OSes may vary)

Comment: The filename shall be unique and you should have the permissions to create a file in the folder where the file will reside. E.g., try `/tmp/my_socket` and it should work. If you want to reuse the same name for your connections then do `Sys.remove` before binding if the file exists already. Otherwise, you can generate filenames using `Filename.temp_file` or implement your own scheme (common practice is to use the pid of the process as a part of the name).